# How to encode spaces in sharepoint 2013 search rest api url?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, search, rest

In a sharepoint 2013 search rest url, I have multiple columns to filter on, but some of the values have spaces, but it seems spaces are used to delimit the filters. How can I encode spaces? See this for an example

This gets 0 record

```
http://mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:News Page Channel:Corporate'&rowlimit=1
```

While both of these get 1

```
http://mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='Channel:Corporate'&rowlimit=1

http://mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:News Page'&rowlimit=1
```

There is a space in `News Page` btw.

How can I encode it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Embrace the content type which contains space within double quotes like **"News Page Channel"**.

```
http://mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:"News Page Channel":Corporate'&rowlimit=1
```

This worked for me. I hope it works for you also.

Note: Any parameter with space in search query should be embraced with double quotes( **"** ).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with encoding. Have you tried

```
http://mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:News Page'&querytext='Channel:Corporate'&rowlimit=1
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, how can you even have two parameters with same key?

Comment: this has a double `querytext` declaration

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with encoding. The easiest way to find out the correct format for your REST API URL is to download the [SharePoint Search Query Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/).

[image]

Once you put the site url (step 1) and the authentication (step 2),
you can put query text to the query box (step 3)

The red box on the top will be the REST API URL. As you can see, my content type also has a space.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this tagged as javascript too, I assume that is where you get this value. You can try:

```
encodeURI (string)
decodeURI (string)
```

I havent used the REST services before so I cannot attest to whether the encoding is actually your issue.